# istringstream - how to do this?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a file:

```
a 0 0
b 1 1
c 3 4
d 5 6
```

Using istringstream, I need to get a, then b, then c, etc. But I don't know how to do it because there are no good examples online or in my book.

Code so far:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("file.txt");
string line;

getline(file,line);
istringstream iss(line);
iss >> id;

getline(file,line);
iss >> id;
```

This prints "a" for id both times. I don't know how to use istringstream obviously and I HAVE to use istringstream. Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ifstream file;
file.open("file.txt");
string line;

getline(file,line);
istringstream iss(line);
iss >> id;

getline(file,line);
istringstream iss2(line);
iss2 >> id;

getline(file,line);
iss.str(line);
iss >> id;
```

`istringstream` copies the string that you give it.  It can't see changes to `line`.  Either construct a new string stream, or force it to take a new copy of the string.

Comment: I was hoping this wasn't the case but I added iss2 in a loop so it would reinitialize every time and that has worked fine. Thanks

Comment: it's important to always call `iss.clear()` after you set a new string with `iss.str(line)`

Comment: What should I change if I want to print all three elements of every line and in each line, the separator is a comma `,` rather than a space ` `?

Answer (score 8):

You could also do this  by having two while loops :-/ .

```
while ( getline(file, line))
{
    istringstream iss(line);

    while(iss >> term)
    {
        cout << term<< endl; // typing all the terms
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This code snippet extracts the tokens using a single loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if(argc != 2) {
        return(1);
    }

    std::string file = argv[1];
    std::ifstream fin(file.c_str());

    char i;
    int j, k;
    std::string line;
    std::istringstream iss;
    while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
        iss.clear();
        iss.str(line);
        iss >> i >> j >> k;
        std::cout << "i=" << i << ",j=" << j << ",k=" << k << std::endl;
    }
    fin.close();
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmofrad solved it very simply and elegantly.
If we abandon the use of istringstream, there is another solution to the specified problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

if(argc != 2) {
    return(1);
}

string file = argv[1];

ifstream fin(file.c_str());
string q[4]; int a[4]; int b[4];
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    fin >> q[i];
    fin >> a[i];
    fin >> b[i];
}

for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    cout << q[i] << "\t" << a[i] << "\t" << b[i] << endl;
}
fin.close();
return(0);
}
```