# Not getting any output for the below code. Can anyone please check this out

Tags: c++, text

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

struct sourceInfo{
    char myIP[10];
    int port;
    int NoOfNeig;
    char Neighbours[50];
} input;
    
int main()
{
    string mytext;
    int j = 0;
    int r = 0;
    ifstream MyReadFile("/home/wweckumarreddy/UDP/Project_Input/1.txt");
    while (getline(MyReadFile,mytext))
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0){
            if (r == 1){ cout << "myIP = " << strcpy((input.myIP), mytext.c_str()) << endl; }
            r += 1;
            if (r == 2){ cout << "port = " << (istringstream(mytext) >> input.port) << endl; }
            r += 1;
            if (r == 3){ cout << "NoOfNeig = " << (istringstream(mytext) >> input.NoOfNeig) << endl; }
            r += 1;
            if (r == 4){ cout << "Neighbours = " << strcpy((input.Neighbours), mytext.c_str()) << endl; }
        }
        j++;
    }
    MyReadFile.close();
}
```

Problem: Not getting any output for the code. Can anyone please check this out.

Input:

```
10.0.0.1
4767
3
10.0.0.2 127.0.0.1 7238
10.0.0.3 127.0.0.1 4672
10.0.0.4 127.0.0.1 6732
```

Comment: Using strcpy does not make sense for converting a `std::string` to an `int`. An int is not  stored as the character digits. It won't be a copy operation. Instead you may want to make use of istringstream: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323929/istringstream-how-to-do-this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323929/istringstream-how-to-do-this)

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you try to copy a string into an int?

Comment: I want the output as 
myIP = 10.0.0.1
port = 2345
NoOfNeig = 2
Neighbours = 10.0.0.2 127.0.0.1 7238
                       10.0.0.3 127.0.0.1 4672

Comment: generally if we print mytext without ant if conditions i am getting the output with all the values where i have to assign the values to the variables.

Answer (score 2):

> error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’

You are passing a `std::string` object where a `const char*` pointer is expected.  There is no such implicit conversion, hence the error.

[`strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) is a C function, it has no concept of `std::string`, only null-terminated character pointers.

However, `std::string` does provide a [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method for explicitly obtaining a suitable `const char*` pointer, eg:

```cpp
strcpy(input.myIP, mytext.c_str());
...
strcpy(input.Neighbours, mytext.c_str());
```

> error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char*’

You are passing an `int` where a `const char*` pointer is expected. There is no such implicit conversion, hence the error.

You can't use `strcpy()` to convert a `std::string` to an `int`.  Use [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or equivalent function instead, eg:

```cpp
input.port := std::stoi(mytext);
...
input.NoOfNeig = std::stoi(mytext);
```

Alternatively, you could put `myText` into a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and then use its overloaded [`operator>>` that extracts `int` values](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt), eg:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
 
std::istringstream(mytext) >> input.port;
...
std::istringstream(mytext) >> input.NoOfNeig;
```

Comment: errors have been rectified but not getting any output.

Comment: The update you have posted has new compile errors in it, so the code won't run.  You can't write an `istream&` (the return value of `operator>>`) to an `ostream`, so statements like `cout << "port = " << (istringstream(mytext) >> input.port) << endl;` are wrong. Read in the variable first, then print out the variable, not the stream: `istringstream(mytext) >> input.port; cout << "port = " << input.port << endl;`

Comment: You are not getting any output because `r` is never what you expect, so your code never attempts to print anything out to `cout`. You are initializing `r` to 0, so `if (r == 1)` is false, then you increment `r`, so `if (r == 2)` is false, and so on. Next time, use a debugger to figure that out.